# combine keys, values from different arrays within a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$input_string = '<script>some data = 
{
    first: [[111,55],[123,66]],
    theColor: "#000000",
    second: [[111,95],[123,77]]
};
</script>'
```

As you can see, its a complex string, with some possible garbage, as well as two arrays mixed in.  The arrays first dimension are the same in each array, ie, '111' and '123' - this should be the key to the new array created.

So I need to build new arrays, using that key/value pair and produce something like this for the first one:

```
array() {
    '111' =>
    array(2) {
        'first' => 
        string(2) "55"
        'second' =>
        string(2) "95"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it! be more clear!!

Comment: If you show us more code, we might be able to show better solution for the task you are trying to do

Comment: sorry, but literally this is all I have been given - I need to be clear on any assumptions I make when providing the solution.  I'm kinda glad others are finding it hard too and not just me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Regex in order to extract key and values in 2 separated arrays.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD6rM6/1).

```
<?php

$re = "/(\\[?(?:\\[(\\d{1,}),(\\d{1,})\\]))/"; 
$str = '<script>some data = 
{
first: [[111,55],[123,66]],
theColor: "#000000",
second: [[111,95],[123,77]]
};
</script>'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$output = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($matches); ++$i)
{
    // If Key already exists - We push
    if(isset($output[($matches[2][$i])]))
        array_push($output[($matches[2][$i])], $matches[3][$i]);

    // Otherwise we create an array to store possible future values.
    else
        $output[($matches[2][$i])] = array( 0 => $matches[3][$i]);
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($output);
print "</pre>";


?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
[111] => Array
    (
        [0] => 55
        [1] => 95
    )

[123] => Array
    (
        [0] => 66
        [1] => 77
    )

)
```

Ezy Pezy Lemon Squizzy.

Comment: Cello powaa! If my code fits the result you can fill my post as answer.

Comment: OK so here's the thing - u have added newlines into the original string - I am NOT allowed to modify the string itself other than via code :)  Are they necessary for the solution ? I am not great with regex

Comment: U have to escape the input string with mysql_real_escape_string() - There are some non escaped " characters inside of it. After escaped it - Edit your post and give me the real string input declaration if it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, still testing things, the output wasn't quite wot i expected. Will come back soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79634/discussion-between-falt4rm-and-yoyoma).